# Cannot connect to mobilefirst adapter from device

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

Migrated our application from 6.2 to 7.0, the mobile web app works great on the phone as well as manually calling the HTTP js adapters. However when exported the apk to a phone, the application starts up but when invoking an adapter for data a 403 error is returned:

```
{"status":403,"invocationContext":null}
```

and the only server log:

```
"POST /SFMobileStudent/authorization/v1/clients/instance HTTP/1.1" 403 64 "-" "WLNativeAPI(bullhead; MMB29Q; Nexus 5X; SDK 23; Android 6.0.1)"
```

The adapter is doesn't have any security on it either

```
securityTest="wl_unprotected"
```

Not sure what we are missing, is there added/required security for 7.0?

Not a whole lot there but you can see the traffic from the device (comcast) to the server. I don't know what any of it means, just sort of repeats. tcpdump packet capture:

> removed

LogCat

> I/chromium(29279): [INFO:CONSOLE(1082)] "processMessage failed: Message: F09 WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin170261306 {"wlFailureStatus":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","status":403,"responseText":"\n\n403 Forbidden</title>\n</head>\nForbidden</h1>\n
>
> You don't have permission to access /SFMobileStudent/authorization/v1/clients/instance\non this server.</p>\n
>
> ---
>
> \nIBM_HTTP_Server at mobilet.sfcollege.edu Port 443</address>\n</body></html>\n","statusText":"Unexpected errorCode occurred. Please try again."}", source: file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/cordova.js (1082)

More logCat

> W/PluginManager(11209): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin.getClientInstanceIdHeader blocked the main thread for 170ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
>   D/dalvikvm(11035): GC_EXPLICIT freed 153K, 39% free 8875K/14500K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 49ms
>   I/ConvCursor(11035): ConversationCursor caching complete pos=18
>   E/ThermalDaemon(  356): set temp 65000 to name /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/temp1_max
>   E/ThermalDaemon(  356): set temp -128000 to name /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/temp1_max_hyst
>   D/dalvikvm(11209): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.SFStudent-1/libauthjni.so 0x41d12ef8
>   D/dalvikvm(11209): Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.SFStudent-1/libauthjni.so' already loaded in same CL 0x41d12ef8
>   D/WifiStateMachine(  917): handleMessage: E msg.what=151572
>   D/WifiStateMachine(  917): processMsg: ConnectedState
>   D/WifiStateMachine(  917): processMsg: L2ConnectedState
>   D/WifiStateMachine(  917): handleMessage: X
>   D/WifiWatchdogStateMachine(  917): Fetch RSSI succeed, rssi=-68 mrssi=-68 txbad=245 txgood=47234
>   D/WifiWatchdogStateMachine(  917): Incremental loss=0/6 Current loss=0% volume=10.06
>   D/WifiWatchdogStateMachine(  917): Cache updated: loss[-68]=0% volume=27.82
>   D/dalvikvm(11209): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2032K, 45% free 8070K/14500K, paused 4ms+2ms, total 57ms
>   D/dalvikvm(11209): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 8ms
>   W/PluginManager(11209): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin.deleteAllAuthData blocked the main thread for 27ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
>   W/PluginManager(11209): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin.getClientInstanceIdHeader blocked the main thread for 97ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
>   D/dalvikvm(11209): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.SFStudent-1/libauthjni.so 0x41d12ef8
>   D/dalvikvm(11209): Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.SFStudent-1/libauthjni.so' already loaded in same CL 0x41d12ef8
>   E/NONE    (11209): [/apps/services/api/SFStudent/android/query] failure. state: 403, response: undefined
>   I/chromium(11209): [INFO:CONSOLE(301)] "Error in Error callbackId: WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin1867260175 : ReferenceError: deferred is not defined", source: file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/cordova.js (301)
>   I/chromium(11209): [INFO:CONSOLE(1080)] "processMessage failed: Error: ReferenceError: deferred is not defined", source: file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/cordova.js (1080)
>   I/chromium(11209): [INFO:CONSOLE(1081)] "processMessage failed: Stack: ReferenceError: deferred is not defined
>   I/chromium(11209):     at Object.InitializeService.WL.Client.invokeProcedure.onFailure (eval at  (file:///android_asset/www/default/js/libs/jquery/jquery-min.js:4:14070), :15:8)
>   I/chromium(11209):     at Object.options.onFailure (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/worklight.js:8806:29)
>   I/chromium(11209):     at Object.onInvokeProcedureFailure [as onFailure] (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/worklight.js:8718:14)
>   I/chromium(11209):     at klass.window.WLJSX.Ajax.WLRequest.WLJSX.Class.create.onFailure (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/worklight.js:3651:26)
>   I/chromium(11209):     at klass.window.WLJSX.Ajax.WLRequest.WLJSX.Class.create.onWlFailure (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/worklight.js:3600:12)
>   I/chromium(11209):     at Object. (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/worklight.js:3440:27)
>   I/chromium(11209):     at Object. (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/wljq.js:1202:33)
>   I/chromium(11209):     at fire (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/wljq.js:1047:30)
>   I/chromium(11209):     at Object.self.fireWith [as rejectWith] (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/wljq.js:1158:7)
>   I/chromium(11209):     at Object.deferred.(anonymous function) [as reject] (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/wljq.js:1247:34)", source: file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/cordova.js (1081)
>   I/chromium(11209): [INFO:CONSOLE(1082)] "processMessage failed: Message: F09 WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin1867260175 {"wlFailureStatus":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","status":403,"responseText":"/*-secure-\n{\"reason\":\"App authenticity security check failed\"}*/","statusText":"Unexpected errorCode occurred. Please try again."}", source: file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/cordova.js (1082)

Comment: can you update from 6.2 to 7.1

Comment: That is surely not the only log available...

Comment: We have already committed to updating to 7.0 not 7.1.

@IdanAdar Where can I find other logs? The first one is the response from WL.Client.invokeProcedure. The 2nd one is the only output from the server when invoking from the installed application.

Comment: The fact that you're getting a 403 makes me wonder exactly what URL it is trying to hit...  Are you able to do anything like a Wireshark or tcpdump packet capture on the server, to examine what the actual requests look like?  Also, is there a complete LogCat log from the device we could look at (assuming you have signed the APK with a debug key so the LogCat would be produced)?

Comment: The apk was signed with our key, so change it to the default keystore? I am not sure how to find the LogCat, from my reading the device needs to be rooted?

I will see if I can get the actual requests from the server.

Comment: If you sign the app with the default debug key, there will be more information produced in LogCat (that is suppressed when the app is signed with a production key).  Not necessarily the actual requests, but more info that can help determine what's going on.  One way to get that log is to hook up the device by USB to a system with the Android SDK on it, and run "adb logcat" on that system while running the app.  However, to see the actual requests and responses to/from the server, using something like Wireshark or tcpdump would be the way to go.

Comment: When the application starts , does it connect to the server ? Or is the invokeprocedure the first connection to the server?

Comment: @patbarron Thanks for the direction, I've added the capture from the server. Working on connecting device to produce the logCat results.

When I use the default key, do I also need to update the war/wlapp on the server to match? Else they won't match when I export the apk.

Comment: @VivinK invokeprocedure is the first connection, is that wrong? Or if there is a upon first starting point to connect to worklight, where would it be or a keyword to look for? I believe in the WL.Client.init the connectOnStartup is false.

Comment: @ZacharyLoughridge - to analyze the packet capture, we'd actually need to look at the captured data (to see what's in the packets).  What we're interested in is to see the request URL that is being sent, that is provoking the 403 status response.  When you rebuild the APK with a debug key, you won't need to redeploy the WAR unless you're using application authenticity protection, since that is the only thing in MFP that cares about the app signing key.

Comment: Also, do note that the use of "connectOnStartup" is deprecated - the normal procedure in 7.0 is to explicitly call WL.Client.connect() in wlCommonInit.

Comment: Also, one other thing - in what you have cited as the "server log" (that actually does seem to show the POST request to a URL that produces a 403) - what server is that from?  IHS, or some other kind of reverse proxy?  It doesn't look like anything that would be in the log from the app server itself.  Do we know that the request is actually getting to the app server, or is it being intercepted and dropped by the reverse proxy.  Sorry for all the questions, there are just a lot of moving parts that have to be looked at.  ;-)

Comment: Based on what we can see in from the tcpdump, looks like you're using HTTPS, so we wouldn't be able to see the content of the packets anyway (at least, not without using something like Wireshark and importing the server's private key).  :-(  So LogCat and server log analysis are probably going to be the most productive avenues to take for the moment....

Comment: @patbarron I saw the connectOnStart up was depreciated, should we change it even though its false?

Correct https, using SSL. Maybe a cert needs to be added to the application somehow?

Comment: No need to change it - just that, since it's deprecated, it could get removed from some future version with no further notice.  If you want to attempt to connect to the server right up front, before calling invokeProcedure, you should call WL.Client.connect() in wlCommonInit (or at least, at some point before you invoke the procedure).  I would think a certificate problem would manifest in some different way, not as a 403 return.  But without seeing all the logs (the app server log, the reverse proxy log, and the LogCat log), it's hard to tell really.

Comment: if you working local then  move on your production server or  In a fresh installation of the ADT plug-in, it is bundled only with the latest available API Level. You might want to use the SDK Manager and add additional API Levels, such as 17, 18,  19, 21. also please share your client side  adapter invoking  the code.

Comment: @patbarron Added the logCat. So far this is the only relevant thing I could find.

Comment: @IdanAdar I've added the logCat, can you advise?

Comment: @ZacharyLoughridge - the LogCat indicates that app authenticity checking is failing.  Did you redeploy the app after rebuilding it with the debug key?

Comment: Is building with the debug key required when running the device in debug mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved. There is a new tag within the application-descriptor:

> directUpdateAuthenticityPublicKey

Updated, exported the application with the keystore and all now works. Thanks for the help.

The issue:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21970348

Comment: Can you clearly explain what you have done there ? You have added `WL.Client.connect` call before adapter call or you have added that `directUpdateAuthenticityPublicKey` because answer link and answer are different